# Nginx - Proxying POST requests for the given conditions

Tags: nginx

For all POST requests to nginx.

We want to proxy_pass to upstream server1:8000 when POST request contain test=1

or proxy pass to upstream server2:8080 when POST requests contains test=0

How to configure the above.

Thanks,

M. G.

Comment: It could be much easier and convenient to put this condition to request uri.

Comment: @Alexey Ten - the $request_uri does not work for POST method.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: @Alexey Ten - $request_uri variable only works for GET method

Comment: You're wrong. `$request_uri` existence does not depend on http method. I mean that you could send post to `/uri/?test=0` or `/uri/?test=1` and check `$arg_test` in nginx. Parsing post body is much more difficult and resource consuming.

Comment: @Alexey Ten - e.g. http://server/path/application?test=1 works fine for GET requests, But when request is POST the test=1 will be in payload / body, Hence $request_uri will not work for POST requests.

Comment: It will be payload if you put in in form's input field. It will not if it's in form's action attribute (in case we speak about html forms). Even in PHP (for example) has separate $_GET and $_POST arrays.

Comment: Yes, test=1 is in form, so for this case what is best way forward.